# Tensorflow Dataset API not using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, gpu

**1. Problem :**

I have a `tf.data.Dataset` that I give to a Keras model (tf.python.keras) with `train_on_batch`.

My dataset looks like this :

```
Generate TFRecord path > tf.data.TFRecordDataset > Parse single example > Batch(2) > Map(merge) > Map(normalize) > Map(split to inputs,labels) > Batch(batch_size) > Prefetch(1)
```

I used `RunMetadata` to output a Timeline readable with Chrome.
Looks like `IteratorGetNext` is only ran on the CPU and is eating a significant amount of time.

(I can't post images, `IteratorGetNext` took 617ms, `MEMCPYHtoD` took 58ms and training took 500ms)

I can't seem to find a way to get IteratorGetNext to run on the GPU, even partially. Currently, CPU is used at 100% and GPU at 40-60% at most.

I would expect something like :

`Read from disk > Move from CPU to GPU > Preprocess.`

I am currently using only one GPU, but I plan to use more GPUs later so a scalable solution would be perfect !

By the way, I am using tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 on Windows 10 with CUDA 10.0 and python 3.6.7. I am not using eager mode.
I haven't tried on Ubuntu but it is a possibility.

**2. What I tried :**

I tried using `prefetch_to_device` and `copy_to_device` from `tf.data.experimental`, in several places in the pipeline.

When using `copy_to_device`, IteratorGetNext took twice as long. It looked like it was copying on the GPU to only copy back to the CPU because the `MEMCPYHtoD` was still present after IteratorGetNext.

I tried replacing Keras' `train_on_batch` with `session.run(train_op)` but it did not really improve, the only change I noticed was that some prefetching actually happened, reducing IteratorGetNext time for a few samples (independent of the amount I put in "prefetch").

By the way, `prefetch(1)` or `prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` did not seem to have any impact.

I tried `session.run` both with and without `copy_to_device`.

I also tried to put the building of the dataset in `with tf.device("/gpu:0")`.

**3. Some code :**

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(self.random_shard_filepath_generator,
                                                 output_types=tf.string,
                                                 output_shapes=())

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(dataset)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda serialized_shard: self.parse_shard(serialized_shard, output_labels))

dataset = dataset.batch(self.shards_per_sample)
dataset = dataset.map(self.join_shards_randomly)
dataset = dataset.map(self.normalize_batch)
dataset = dataset.map(self.split_batch_io)

dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)

autoencoder.train_on_batch(dataset)
```

Finally, I would add that my model may just not be big enough and I could improve the ratio by just making it "bigger", but it does not feel like a great solution.

-- Edit :

I had :

```py
...
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
autoencoder.train_on_batch(dataset)
```

Which I changed to :

```py
...
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
dataset_iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
dataset_initializer = dataset_iterator.initializer

session.run(dataset_initializer)

x, y = dataset_iterator
autoencoder.train_on_batch(x, y)
```

Thanks to `EdoardoG` for making me try `MultiDeviceIterator` which made me create an `Iterator` outside of Keras' `train_on_batch`.

Now `IteratorGetNext` only takes about 0.05ms where it took previously about 600ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Dataset API operations are usually run on CPU, so it's actually normal that you cannot run your input pipeline on the GPU.

Someone has written [an iterator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610#issuecomment-411893139) which could solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this one.
I saw it but I did not think I would be useful until I use more than one GPU.
So I tried it and it worked, but actually not thanks to this Iterator.
It made me create and initialize the iterator outside of Keras' `train_function`, and it did the trick. So I tried by creating an iterator with `make_initializable_iterator` and it also worked.

Comment: I'm used to writing plain TF code instead of using Keras because its much more versatile for training GANs and provides me a better understanding of what is going on especially in the train() function and input pipeline. I can't tell if your speedup is due to TF Dataset API or the GPU iterator you used, but I experience often unstable performances by switching between one-shot/initializable/feedable iterators, expecially when using multiple datasets. I also made a long question (still unanswered), maybe I should give that custom iterator a try.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your NN code using `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):` where gpu:0 is is the first gpu in your system.

If you want to use multiple GPUs:

```
for d in ['/device:GPU:2', '/device:GPU:3']:
  with tf.device(d):
    <your code here>
```

Some helpful guidelines from [tensorflow's website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu)

Comment: I tried wrapping my `main()` in `with tf.device("/gpu:0")` first, then the building of the model, and then the main train loop.
It either did not change much or made it worse (up to x3 more time spent on `IteratorGetNext`

As for the multi-gpus, I was aware of this technique, I'm more concerned of distribution of data to multiple GPUs. If the CPU can't provide for 1 GPU, it won't for more GPUs.